# Multiple custom crontab file into one master crontab

Tags: cron

I have some crontab content in different file within a git project. My plan is to add and update these into server's crontab, like merge contents into that one.

I've tried without success (for example):

`sudo crontab /var/www/html/cron1 /var/www/html/cron2`

`sudo cat /var/www/html/cron1 /var/www/html/cron2 > crontab` (and with `>>` too)

Is it possible to write multiple custom "crontab" file into master crontab?

Comment: "_without success_" is not a problem description. What happened in each case? Why was that wrong?

Comment: Nothing happened, only cron1 content went into crontab. My current solution is: `sudo cat /var/www/html/cron1 /var/www/html/cron2 > /var/www/html/merged.cron | sudo crontab /var/www/html/merged.cron`

Comment: Solution: `cat /var/www/html/cron1 /var/www/html/cron2 | sudo crontab -`